# SharePoint REST API URL

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

Hi I am using JavaScript for accessing SharePoint and I can successfully get the List content as long as the ListName is a single word, but when the ListName has two words by JavaSript fails.

For example:

```
url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Product')/items" = OK
url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Product Name')/items" = NO OK
```

Thank you for any help.

EDIT
[Click to see the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xrrc.jpg)

Comment: @AmayKulkarni please click the link to see the error.

Comment: change to: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Product%20Name')/items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `encodeURIComponent()` function. It'll convert your string to browser-acceptable format.

`encodeURIComponent("getbytitle('Product Name')")`
will be
`getbytitle('Product%20Name')"`

So in your case if title can be changed it should be:

```
var title = "Can be few words";
var siteUrl = "blabla";
var url = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + encodeURIComponent(title) + "')/items";
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: @Ado: clarified my answer

Comment: Still not work, please click the link to see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the space in the list name, like this:

```
url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProductName')/items"
```